# What do I link in to define boost::thread_specific_ptr and related?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, linker, undefined-symbol

I want to use boost::thread_specific_ptr but need to know what to add to my gcc v3.4.6 link line to define what it uses:

```
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:35: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::thread_resource_error()'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6detail3tssC1EPNS_9function1IvPvSaINS_13function_baseEEEE+0x5b):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:35: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::~thread_resource_error()'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6detail3tssC1EPNS_9function1IvPvSaINS_13function_baseEEEE+0x60):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:35: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::thread_resource_error'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6detail3tssC1EPNS_9function1IvPvSaINS_13function_baseEEEE+0x76):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:38: undefined reference to `boost::detail::tss::init(boost::function1<void, void*, std::allocator<boost::function_base> >*)'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6detail3tssC1EPNS_9function1IvPvSaINS_13function_baseEEEE+0xd2):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:43: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::thread_resource_error()'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6detail3tssC1EPNS_9function1IvPvSaINS_13function_baseEEEE+0xf8):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:43: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::~thread_resource_error()'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost6detail3tssC1EPNS_9function1IvPvSaINS_13function_baseEEEE+0xfd):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:43: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::thread_resource_error'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZNK5boost19thread_specific_ptrIN5Botan14AutoSeeded_RNGEE3getEv+0x11): In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG>::get() const':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:89: undefined reference to `boost::detail::tss::get() const'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost19thread_specific_ptrIN5Botan14AutoSeeded_RNGEE5resetEPS2_+0x2f): In function `boost::thread_specific_ptr<Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG>::reset(Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG*)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:97: undefined reference to `boost::detail::tss::set(void*)'
../../src/utility/ARCH.linux_26_i86/debug/libmyApp.a(system.o)(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost19thread_specific_ptrIN5Botan14AutoSeeded_RNGEE5resetEPS2_+0x4a):/usr/include/boost/thread/tss.hpp:98: undefined reference to `boost::detail::tss::cleanup(void*)'
```

What should I be linking in to define all of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system I use `-lboost_thread` (since `libboost_thread.so` is already in my `/usr/lib` I don't need any `-L` options).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `CMake`, you can:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(you_lib
                     ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```